# User control incorrectly displaying in modalpopup extender

Tags: user-controls, modalpopup

I'm placing a user control inside a modal popup.  The problem is that it is getting displayed even before the popup is being invoked.  If I replace the user control with anything else, it is hidden correctly.  The moment I put back in the user control, I get the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="plSearch" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="365">
    <uc1:Search ID="searchSponsor" runat="server" Mode="ReturnID" />
    <asp:Button ID="SearchCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSearch" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSponsor" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="lbSearch"
    PopupControlID="plSearch" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="False"
    Enabled="True" CancelControlID="SearchCancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When I moved the linkbutton that was named as the modalpopup's TargetControlID to immediately above the mpe, it displayed correctly.